# ansible vmware-tools playbook

Tags: ansible, vmware-tools

I am trying to create a playbook that will see if `"/etc/vmware-tools/services.sh"` is running if not running then start.

I have tried command and shell but I can't figure the `syntax` for a conditional.

```
    --- # VMWARE_TOOLS_NOT_RUNNING
- hosts: redhat-vm-guest
  user: ansible-user
  become: true
  become_user: root
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: check vmware tools is running
    command: /etc/vmware-tools/services.sh status
    register: status
  - name: print status
    debug:
      msg: "{{ status.stdout }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
- name: check vmware tools is running
  command: /etc/vmware-tools/services.sh status
  register: _status
  ignore_errors: True

- name: Start VMWare Tools
    command: /etc/vmware-tools/services.sh start
  when: _status.stdout.find("running") == -1
```

I recommend using the `service` module if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have something that works.

```
    --- # VMWARE_TOOLS_NOT_RUNNING
- hosts: vmwaretools
  user: ansibleuser
  become: true
  become_user: root
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: vmware tools status
    command: /etc/vmware-tools/services.sh status
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: _status
  - debug: msg="{{ _status.stdout }}"
  - name: start vmware tools
    command: "/etc/vmware-tools/services.sh start"
    ignore_errors: yes
    when: _status == _status
  - debug: msg="{{ _status.stdout }}"
```